# Timeline code for TileMill/MapBox

Tags: javascript, html, mapbox, tilemill, timeline.js

I'm looking to write code to implement a sliding timeline tool, which I hope to be useto visualize the opening/closing of businesses and organizations on a map that I have created using TileMill/Mapbox.  The map's data has start and end dates for each data point.  Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

there are a few options for building a timeline coordinated with the markers.
Not sure what the data looks like, it seems you need to separate the markers from the basemap layer. A good start could be looking how these examples are done:

- D3 + Mapbox: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/timeline-scaled-markers/
- Leaflet: http://dwilhelm89.github.io/LeafletSlider/